# Spring boot: how to read specific property from application.yml and ignore others

Tags: spring, properties

My goal is to read some property from application.yml file and ignore other properties. This is need for testing purposes - I want to read part of config and validate it. I want to ignore other properties because Spring Boot tring to handle it but this is no need for my test.
Example.

Config:

```
first:
 property:
  {cipher}value    #for example Spring trying to handle cipher and throws exception

second:
 property:
  value
```

Class (**using String for simplification**):

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.property")
  public String secondProperty() {
      return new String();
  }
}
```

Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ConfigPropertiesCheckerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    String secondProperty;

    @Test
    void checkAutoConfigEndpointProperties() {
        assertThat(secondProperty, is(notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

So question: how to ignore `first.property` and say Spring just skip it?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `{cipher}`ed properties decryption with `spring.cloud.decrypt-environment-post-processor.enabled=false`. E.g:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.cloud.decrypt-environment-post-processor.enabled=false")
```